# Listening to Youtube Upload Event Java

Tags: java, youtube-api

How would I go about listening for an upload event on a specific channel with the Youtube API. I have a system in place but it can only check a certain amount of times before the rate limit is implemented.

Cheers,
Agent

Answer (score 1):

I susgest you have a look at [Subscribe to Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications)  section of the documentation.

> The YouTube Data API (v3) supports push notifications via PubSubHubbub, a server-to-server publish/subscribe protocol for Web-accessible resources.

> Use the Google hub to subscribe to receive push notifications:
>
> - Set the mode to subscribe. (Or set the mode to unsubscribe to cancel a >subscription.)
> - Set the callback URL to the URL that you set up in step 1.
> - Set the topic URL to [https://www.youtube.com/xml/feeds/videos.xml?>channel_id=CHANNEL_ID](https://www.youtube.com/xml/feeds/videos.xml?%3Echannel_id=CHANNEL_ID), where CHANNEL_ID is the YouTube channel ID for which you want to retrieve push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so Youtube has a feed (url: https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=%channel_id%) that I believe doesn't have a rate limit. Therefore, by editing my code to get the latest entry and get the video id from that, my code works. I found that url from line 115 in [here](https://github.com/Androz2091/DiscordYoutubeNotifier/blob/master/index.js)